# How to find the mean and standard deviation of a date column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Name'] = ['Ankita', 'Ankita', 'Ankita', 'Ankita', 'Ankita', 'Yashvardhan', 'Yashvardhan', 'Yashvardhan', 'Yashvardhan', 'Yashvardhan']
df['Date'] = ['2014-10-07', '2015-03-30', '2015-12-07', '2015-12-09', '2017-01-30', '2017-01-30', '2018-02-19', '2018-02-23', '2018-11-19', '2020-01-23']
df['Value'] = [2200, 75, 100, 22, 98, 0.36, 57, 29, 1026, 1296]
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

How can I get the mean and standard deviation of the `df['Date']` column? It seems that I can do `df['Date'].mean()` to get the average date, but it gives me the following error when I tried `df['Date'].std()`:

```
TypeError: cannot perform std with type datetime64[ns]
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: pandas 1.2.1, cannot replicate the issue.

Comment: same with 1.3.1. try updating your version?

Comment: Thanks! It seems that I only have a Pandas of version 1.1.5, but it tells me `Requirement already satisfied: pandas in ./env/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.1.5)` when I tried `pip3 install --upgrade pandas`

Comment: I also tried `pip install pandas==1.3.1` but it gives me `ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==1.3.1`

Comment: You can't upgrade your version of pandas probably because your version of python is unsupported by pandas 1.3.1 (Officially Python 3.7.1 and above, 3.8, and 3.9.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you have to use numpy and change the datetime64 format to int64 by using `.astype()` and then put it back to a datetime format.

Here is how you can do it

```
import numpy as np
pd.Timestamp(df['Date'].astype(np.int64).std())
```

Note : You will see that if you do the same with the mean

```
pd.Timestamp(df['Date'].astype(np.int64).mean())
```

You will find the same value as `df['Date'].mean()`, in case you want to have a double check.

Comment: Thanks! Could you briefly explain why would it return `1971-09-10` for the standard deviation?

Comment: @KaihuaHou the code is converting the datetime into nanoseconds passed after 1970, finding the standard deviation (or mean) in nanoseconds, and then converting those nanoseconds back into a timestamp as the date and time when that number of nanoseconds passed after Jan-1-1970 (apparently about 21 months). Depending on what you wanted to know, this is probably fine for mean but for std, I would not convert back to timestamp, but rather to seconds (div by 1e9) or days (div by 8.64e130).